# Reusing Validation Attributes in MVC5

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have been doing a lot of research on validation and how it works.  I understand that we can use attributes or even make custom attributes which we can throw over our ViewModels to validate that data.  While this is all working fine, I am finding myself to be reusing same combination of attributes on multiple ViewModels.

For example, lets take a "Name", in project X a name, whether it is a Movie Name, Book Name, Person First Name, Last Name, etc... it is a name after all and as such I tend to apply 90% of the validation attributes the same.  Required, Minimum length 3, Maximum length 50, only letters, spaces, etc... you get the picture.

Now I end up with a variable that has 5+ attributes stacked on it.  These are pre-built attributes that I would prefer not to code again as they are already coded for me.  So my question is this:

How can I create a CustomValidateName attribute, which will validate for all of those things, provide different error messages based on what is wrong and at the same time, reuse some of the built in attributes in .NET framework so that I am not re-inventing the wheel.  The bottom line here is that whenever I have a Name variable, I can now just put this one attribute instead of the normal 5+.

Comment: Have you considered a base view model with that property and its validation attributes

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have, but I feel I would have these chains of objects extending each other and would make debugging a nightmare.  Or I would have 1 base object that has a lot of stuff being used by couple view models but not all which would make it cluttered and again hard to debug.  I wished to see if it would be possible to create a custom attribute and in there reference other attributes and provide custom error messages based on the outcome.

Comment: There are a few issues: 1) Validations are typically similar but not identical across layers or even views. For example an Insert form is more relaxed than an Update form. The POST API behing the Insert form though would be stricter. You could end up having 15-20 different settings in one file away from their point of use (4-5 per scenario), rather than 5 attributes on the ViewModel that actually needs them. 2) controls and libraries know about the DataAnottation attributes. You'd have to replicate a lot of functionality

Comment: You could use Action filters instead of attributes, although I'm not sure what performance impact this would have

Comment: You could reverse engineer [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations) to see how it is done. Note [how to register the validator with MVC](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations#what-about-the-support-of-aspnet-mvc-client-side-validation). `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.FirstOrDefault(x => x is DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider));` and `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ExpressiveAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider());`

Answer (score 1):

Use Can create custom Validation for your all validation

For Example :

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  

namespace Custom_DataAnnotation_Attribute.Models  
{  
    public class CustomEmailValidator : ValidationAttribute  
    {  
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)  
        {  
            if (value != null)  
            {  
                string email = value.ToString();  

                if (Regex.IsMatch(email, @"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))  
                {  
                    return ValidationResult.Success;  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                    return new ValidationResult("Please Enter a Valid Email.");  
                }  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is required");  
            }  
        }
```

Above method generate validation for both required nd Email type

You can Add More validation In this method Using If Else or Switch and revert the custome message

**At Model:**

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  

namespace Custom_DataAnnotation_Attribute.Models  
{  
    public class EmployeeModel  
    {  
        public string Name { get; set; }  

        [CustomEmailValidator]  
        public string Email { get; set; }  
        public string Password { get; set; }  
        public string Mobile { get; set; }          
    }  
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Do you see that line of code that says if regex ismatch?  That check can already be accomplished by putting attribute `[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]`  So at this point it is re-inventing the wheel.  I am trying to reuse my above line of code inside that custome attribute, I shouldn't have to write my own validation if it already exists.  The other problem is see how you have returned just one error?  I'd rather validate it all and return all the errors to the user so he doesn't go off submitting 5 times.